# Table does not give expected result with `30 but right with `40

Tags: machine-precision, table

I want Mathematica to generate a table, but I am very confused by its behaviour.

```
tab = Table[i, {i, 6.311, 6.312, 0.001}]
```

Now I get the desired result, namely {6.311, 6.312}.

But in my actual code I want to solve a differential equation for different values of i to a very high precision. But when I do this

```
tab = Table[i, {i, 6.311`30, 6.312`30, 0.001`30}]
```

The result that I get is {6.31100000000000000000000000000}, so only 1 value instead of two.

But this

```
tab = Table[i, {i, 6.311`40, 6.312`40, 0.001`40}]
```

Gives the desired result again, namely {6.311000000000000000000000000000000000000, 
6.312000000000000000000000000000000000000}.

I really have no clue what is happening, and I hope someone could enlighten me because I have been breaking my head about it.

Comment: My first guess is floating-point round-off error causing trouble at the end point, but I can't really show it.  It might be something else...Report it to WRI.  (This also fails: ``Range[6.311`30, 6.312`30, 0.001`30]``.)

Comment: Numbers are stored and evaluated as binary numbers. As a general rule, use exact numbers for known constants to minimize numeric representation issues. `tab = Table[i, {i, 6311/1000, 6312/1000, 1/1000}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon The binary representation didn't seem to be the issue here in my test. In fact, `Table` usually seems to compare with tolerance at the end point (e.g. `Table[i, {i, 0, 3, 3*0.1}]`, even though `3 * 0.1` is a bit greater than `0.3` and the table end a bit past `3.`)

Comment: @MichaelE2 - I wouldn't draw any conclusions about arbitrary-precision comparisons by looking at machine precision examples. "Approximate numbers with machine precision or higher are considered equal if they differ in at most their last seven binary digits (roughly their last two decimal digits)" I don't know how many guard bits are used/considered when working with arbitrary precision, but there are none with machine precision.

Comment: @BobHanlon The number of guard bits can vary, but the "last seven binary digits" means the last seven significant ones. In any case, none of the bits of ``6.311`30 + 0.001`30`` and ``6.312`30`` appear to be different. (If Mma is using the guard bits as significant in comparisons under the hood, that's a bug. They shouldn't.)

Comment: @Charlotte, Another possible workaround is `Table[..., {i, Subdivide[a, b, n]}]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know exactly what the problem is (so it seems to be a bug), but here are a couple of workarounds:

```
Block[{$MinPrecision = 30},
 Table[i, {i, 6.311`30, 6.312`30, 0.001`30}]
 ]

(*
  {6.31100000000000000000000000000,
   6.31200000000000000000000000000}
*)
```

If you don't want to set the min precision for your whole code, you can isolate the setting for the iterator this way:

```
Table[i,
 {i, 
  Block[{$MinPrecision = 30}, 
   Range[6.311`30, 6.312`30, 0.001`30]]}
 ]

(*
  {6.31100000000000000000000000000, 
   6.31200000000000000000000000000} 
*)
```

And of course, one can use 40-digit precision as the OP observed.